# graph using Android GraphView

Tags: android, graph, android-graphview

Did someone know how to make graph something like this: [link](http://mobilearninginc.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/iOS-Simulator-Screen-shot-May-30-2014-1.58.32-AM.png) on Android using Android GraphView? And can send me a example code? I trying but I do not know how to print valid x values, I am got only this, on picture. Tnx.

[image: Spend by category]

Answer (score 0):

the rotated labels are not possible out-of-the-box in android graphview. But the other styles should be possible. Take a look at the GraphView-Demos project and the documentation.

http://android-graphview.org/